# Retrieve the latest Documents from ElasticSearch in Ascending Order

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to retrieve the last 3 documents from a set, taking into account that the desired elements order is given by a field named *created*. To do that I'm exploiting the combination of *sort + order* mechanism, as also pointed out in many SO Q&A:

- [Return the most recent record from ElasticSearch index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723379/return-the-most-recent-record-from-elasticsearch-index)
- [Sorting and latest records in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607808/sorting-and-latest-records-in-elasticsearch)
- [Get last document from ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062504/get-last-document-from-elasticsearch)

Note: The field *created* in my case is a timestamp but wrapped on a long.

```
{
    "size" : 3,
    "sort": [
    {
      "created": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But with this stratagem the results are retrieved in descending order. I'd like them to be returned in ascending order. Which way may I combine these two requirements?

Example, having this set (in the form `field:value;`):

```
doc:A; created:1;
doc:C; created:2;
doc:F; created:3;
doc:D; created:4;
doc:B; created:5;
doc:H; created:6;
doc:G; created:7;
```

I want to retrieve the last three documents according to *created*, which is OK using the above query, but the results are given in in the order *G, H, B* corresponding to the value *7, 6, 5*, while I would like to keep the order *B, H, G*, corresponding to the values *5, 6, 7* of the field *created*.

Comment: To change the order it's enough to change the value {
      "created": {
        "order": "asc"
      } .

Comment: He wont have the 3 last created doc if he do that...He would have the older ones.

Comment: You can handle this at application side. Loop through the `hits` array in reverse order.

Comment: @NishantSaini Right now I'm handling this programmatically. So, it seems like the answer is that this is not possible just relying on ElasticSearch.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is `order result -> limit result (size) -> reorder limited result`. This is not possible via elastic.